# is picking from array is costlier then simple if else statement

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

Below is the answer to [this problem](https://www.codechef.com/problems/HCODE01) which is judged as AC

```
n=input()
t=int(n[-2:])
d=t%4
if(d==0):
    print(n)
elif(d==1):
    print("1")
elif(d==2):
    print(int(n)+1)
else:
    print("0")
```

I have submitted a code like this.

```
n = input()
t = int(n[-2:])
d = t % 4
print( [n, "1", int(n) + 1, "0"][d])
```

What i want to know is why this is causing time limit exceeded.
Does picking a value from an array using index is that much costlier then
a simple if..elif ... else routine.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I should have mentioned it is in python3.6

Comment: Can you please provide the *input* for which this is failing? See the [mcve] page on what your code sample should satisfy to help us help you.

Comment: Maybe your time limit is exceeded for a more fundamental issue with your chosen approach.  A question like this looks like it could be designed to exceed time limit if you actually XOR every integer in the range, or overlook a critical optimization.  I would imagine there's a trick you're missing.

Comment: Indexing is fast, but building the list to index may be slower than the worst-case scenario of 3 failed comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

To build on @chepner's comment, the difference is negligible at the bottom of the constraint range, however at the top of the constraint range, constructing the array is causing a significant increase in run-times.

Running timeit on the first code sample with an input of `n=4` yields

```
114 µs ± 2.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

vs

```
113 µs ± 3.54 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

for your code sample.
Unfortunately when you build the array for very large inputs (see the example at the top range of the constraint `n=10^10^5`)

The first code sample yields

```
159 ms ± 2.62 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

vs

```
200 ms ± 4.45 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

for your code sample.